# Ruby : Finding lowest free ID in an ID array

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, arraylist

I have an array with different IDs going from 1 to 4000. I need to add some elements in a database with an ID that would go in that array. Since the biggest ID possible is 4000 (which is not that much in my case), I'd like to be able to find the lowest unused ID possible I could use for my new element.

I would know how to do that in C++, but since I'm pretty new in Ruby, I'm asking for help. in C++, I would write a loop in which I would check if array[i] == array[i+1] - 1. If not the case, then the new id would be array[i] + 1.

I have just no idea how to write that in Ruby.

Comment: This leads to id 1 referring to apples in january, but maybe to bananas in february. Normal procedure is letting the database manage the id collumn. The fact that you have a maximum of 4000 makes it look like the id's have a meaning (like 0-4000 is category food, 4001-5000 is toys) - a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
(1..4000).to_a.-(array).min
```

Comment: +1 @sawa, very nice and concise. Should run very quickly also.

Comment: this is indeed very, very clever

Comment: I used this one and it is working perfectly, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Using a range, you can find the first element that is not part of your array:

```
array = [1,2,3,5,6]
(1..4000).find { |i| !array.include?(i) }
# => 4
```

Comment: this might be very inefficient because the include? method could be called many thousand times (it's quadratic complexity)

Comment: Yeah, there definitely is some slowness the higher the first available id is (when it' 3999, there's a noticeable delay). Other answers address this.

Answer (score 3):

```
def first_unused_id(ids)
  index = ids.each_index.find{|i| ids[i] + 1 != ids[i+1] }
  ids[index] + 1
end
```

Some explanation:

- [each_index](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/each_index) will transform the array into an [Enumerator](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator) giving the arrays indices.
- [find](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/find) will return the first element that returns `true` from the block passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

how about this one:

```
(1..4000).find { |i| array[i-1] != i }
```

similar to Dylan's answer but in this case, it simply checks whether the [n-1]th member of the array is n.  If not, that index is "open" and is returned.  This solution only requires one check per index, not 4000...

so for

```
array = [1,2,3,5,6]
```

this would find that array[4-1] != 4  (because array[3] = 5) and return 4 as the first available id.

(this requires a sorted array of indices but that has been assumed so far)

Comment: That would be off by one -- `array[0]` would be 1, not 0; it should be `array[i-1]`. Also, the code you posted doesn't work at all as is, since `!array[i]` will always be `false`. It should be `array[i-1] != i`

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]

def lowest_unused(ids)
  ids.find { |e| ids.index(e) + 1 != e } - 1
end

p lowest_unused(array) # 4
```

Comment: similar to Jakub Hampl's answer but a bit simpler